# Error running Tomcat 7 from intellij Idea 11

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Java 7 and Tomcat 7 with IDE Intellij Idea 11. I am using window 7. My application is getting compiled successfully from Intellij Idea 11 but when I try to run it in run or debug mode from Intellij Idea, I am getting the following error:

Error running Tomcat 7:
cannot load C:\Users\USERNAME.intellijIdea11\system\tomcat\Unnamed_ohm\conf\web.xml

As a result, it's not launching my application. I checked that web.xml do exist there at the above specified path.

Can you please help me what I am missing and what should be done to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: With all those sevens I think you should use IntelliJ IDEA 7. (Just kidding).

Comment: We need more details to investigate this problem, please contact JetBrains Support for the instructions how to obtain the required log files.